# Allow reverse proxy cache but not browser cache

Tags: http, caching, proxy

There are so many questions asking "how to make sure the pages are not cached", and answers like "this is how to instruct the both clients and proxy servers not to cache". I'm instead looking for a way to achieve "allow proxy cache but not clients (i.e. browsers) cache".

In fact, I found that setting no cache-related headers can achieve this, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it and there's no explicit way of instructing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the HTTP jargon these caches are referred as `shared` or `public` (proxy) and `private` caches (browser).
You should use a response header similar to this:

```
cache-control: public, max-age=0, s-maxage=${seconds}
```

Being `${seconds}` the TTL of the cached elements. The key here is using the directive [`s-maxage`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3).

> If a response includes an s-maxage directive, then for a shared cache (but not for a private cache), the maximum age specified by this directive overrides the maximum age specified by either the max-age directive or the Expires header. The s-maxage directive also implies the semantics of the proxy-revalidate directive (see section 14.9.4), i.e., that the shared cache must not use the entry after it becomes stale to respond to a subsequent request without first revalidating it with the origin server. The s- maxage directive is always ignored by a private cache.

Notice that this header does not exempt the browser from caching the resource (using it to serve a future request), but instead forces it to revalidate its content (if a last-modified or etag header is also returned)

Comment: so sorry for my late-accept and thanks for telling me the terms.